# How to reset tty after exec-ed program crashes?

Tags: linux, bash, tty

I am writing a Ruby wrapper around Docker and `nsenter`. One of the command my tool provides is to start a Bash shell within a container. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
payload = "sudo nsenter --target #{pid(container_name)} --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid -- env #{env} /bin/bash -i -l;"
Kernel.exec(payload)
```

In Ruby, [`Kernel#exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) relies on the `exec(2)` syscall, hence there is no fork.
One issue is that the container sometime dies prematurely which effectively kills my newly created Bash prompt. I then get back the prompt originally used to run my Ruby tool, but I cannot see what I am typing anymore, the tty seems broken and running reset effectively solves the issue.

I'd like to conditionally run `reset` if the program I exec-ed crashes. I found that the following works well:

```
$ ./myrubytool || reset
```

Except I'd like to avoid forcing people using my tool to append `|| reset` every time.

I have tried the following:

> payload = "(sudo nsenter --target #{pid(container_name)} --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid -- env #{env} /bin/bash -i -l) || reset;"

But this surprisingly puts `reset` in the background (i.e. I can run reset by entering `fg`). One benefit is that the tty is working properly, but it's not really ideal.

Would you have any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If terminal echo has been disabled in a terminal, then **you can run the command `stty echo` to re-enable the terminal echo.** (Conversely, `stty -echo` disables terminal echo, and `stty -a` displays all terminal settings.)

This is safe to run even if terminal echo is already enabled, so if you want to play it safe, you can do something like `./myrubytool ; stty echo` which will re-enable terminal echo if it is disabled regardless of the exit status of your Ruby program. You can put this in a shell script if you want to.

It might be that there is a way to execute a command when the Ruby program exits (often referred to as a "trap"), but I'm not familiar enough with Ruby to know whether such capabilities exist.

However, if you are creating a script for general use, **you probably should look into more robust techniques and not rely on workarounds.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I do not really control when Docker containers crashes. I have made my command more robust by testing for open ports before trying to run nsenter (this makes sure the container is running correctly). This effectively prevents the issue from happening, but I am still curious to find an explanation why Bash puts programs in the background, and if there is a way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It should do exactly what you want.
It runs the command in a separate process, waits on it, and if, when it finishes, the return value is not 0, it runs the command `reset`.

```
payload = "sudo nsenter --target #{pid(container_name)} --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid -- env #{env} /bin/bash -i -l;"
fork { Kernel.exec(payload) }
pid, status = Process.wait2
unless status.exitstatus == 0
     system("reset")
end
```

**EDIT**
If all you want to do is turn echo back on, change the `system("reset")` line to `system("stty echo")`.

Comment: Do note that `reset` does a lot more than just turn terminal echo back on. I realize it's what the OP wrote about using currently, but it isn't necessarily at all the best tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this puts the main process in the background (thus I need to do 'fg' to get reset running). My guess is that when in interactive mode, Bash cannot run more than one program at the time, therefore it puts stuff in the background.

In your code, the forked process runs the payload interactively and Bash puts the main process in the background.

Comment: @Janitrix Your explanation of why it doesn't work doesn't make sense. It works perfectly for me. `bash` isn't putting the payload in the "background"; my code is (and it isn't in `bash`'s background either; `fg` doesn't change anything).