# Exiting terminal output ending with END

Tags: bash, terminal

I have come across command line tools that display output, and ends the output with END, like so:

```
arbitrary output..
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

My issue is, I cannot use `Ctrl + Z`, `Ctrl + C` or any other command combination that I know of to exit this, which means I have to close my terminal each time it occurs.

How do i stop an output like the above, and return to where I was in the terminal?

Comment: It's possible that it only *appears* as though the program has not exited. Perhaps the command has modified the tty so that it is difficult to tell. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24247226/1707353) might help you reset your tty if echo has been disabled. Using another terminal to check the process list will, of course, make it easier to tell if the program has truly ended.

Comment: By pressing `q`(quit)

Comment: @JeffHolt thanks for the response and reference. I'll take a look at it sometime to get a better understand of how the terminal works. In this case, pressing q did the trick.

Comment: @Ivan thanks, that did it

Answer (score 8):

These command line tools are usually [`less`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) or [`more`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html) utilities. They can be exited just by pressing `q`.